# ChartJS set default options only to specific Canvas, not globally

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have 10+ Charts and all are Line Charts, created using `ChartJS`.

**Chart One**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById(cid).getContext('2d');
Chart.defaults.global.elements.line.tension = 0;
var chartOne = new Chart(ctx, {.....}
```

**Chart Two**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById(cid).getContext('2d');
var chartTwo = new Chart(ctx, {.....}
```

For chartOne I am defining Line `tension` as `0` and chartTwo has no Line Tension configuration, expected to be default of `0.4`.
However chartTwo is taking the Line Tension configuration from chartOne.

How can I set `Chart.defaults` for specific canvas only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purpose of `Chart.defaults` means to have same values for multiple charts so it means you can not have two separate `Chart.defaults` settings.

**Solution:**

After understanding your requirement more clearly, here is what you can do with common properties.
Take all the not common datasets in a `data` var and push common properties in `data` like below and pass that to `datasets` in chart.

```js
var data = [{
  label: 'India',
  data: [50, 55, 45, 43, 39],
  borderColor: '#666699'
}, {
  label: 'UAE',
  data: [15, 22, 19, 17, 19],
  borderColor: '#ff9933'
}, {
  label: 'US',
  data: [75, 62, 77, 81, 77],
  borderColor: '#33cccc'
}, {
  label: 'Oman',
  data: [15, 18, 23, 19, 21],
  borderColor: '#333300'
}, {
  label: 'Qatar',
  data: [26, 28, 27, 25, 26],
  borderColor: '#00cc99'
}, {
  label: 'Canada',
  data: [75, 77, 72, 79, 71],
  borderColor: '#cc33ff'
}, {
  label: 'Australia',
  data: [22, 28, 25, 23, 26],
  borderColor: '#3399ff'
}, {
  label: 'China',
  data: [51, 35, 41, 43, 39],
  borderColor: '#ff0000'
}];


data.forEach(function(obj) {
  obj.pointBackgroundColor = '#fff',
    obj.pointBorderWidth = 2,
    obj.borderWidth = 2,
    obj.lineTension = 0,
    obj.fill = false
});

console.log(data)// pass data var to datasets in chart
```

Complete working [**fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/9mburn8e/27/).

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Since I have 10+ datas in `datasets` of each Chart and every data line will have same `tension` and `borderWidth`. Instead of declaring them for every time, can I set default for the entire chart?

Comment: @theKing can you create a fiddle for this case *10+ datas in datasets of each Chart and every data line will have same tension and borderWidth* and share the link here.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kingBethal/9mburn8e/18/  JSFiddle `pointBackgroundColor`, `pointBorderWidth`, `borderWidth`, `lineTension`, and `fill` are common for all the `line`s

Comment: @theKing please check my updated answer and working fiddle.